# Como fazer uma API Post em ASP.NET Core sem usar MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, postman

Não trabalho com APIs em ASP.NET Core até ter que precisar dela para um projeto escrito em C#. Então, criei com um projeto padrão, com o seguinte controlador:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MetadataProcessController : ControllerBase {
    ...
    ...

    // GET api/MetadataProcess/5
    [HttpGet("{filename}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(string filename)
    {
        return "Hello " + filename;
    }

    // POST api/MetadataProcess
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        return "Hello " + value;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Fazendo chamada usando `Get` através da URL `/api/MetadataProcess/algumaCoisa` o resultado obtido é `Hello algumaCoisa` no navegador.

No entanto, ao chamar pelo `Post` usando o Postman, encodando a seguinte entrada: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O response é um erro em Json:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei inserir outros valores no `value`, mas nada deu certo. O que posso estar fazendo de errado? Gostaria de receber na response um `Hello +` o que foi enviado na request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está enviando um objeto json, porém está pedindo uma string no método. Caso queira receber um objeto, crie uma classe com a propriedade Value:

```
public class Input
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Caso queira apenas uma string, envie de fato uma string:

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 1):

O payload enviado deve ser uma string e não um objeto. Ou seja:

```js
"C%..."
```

Ao invés de

```js
{
   value: "C%..."
}
```